# PHP Guzzle 6 not URL encoding pound/hash

Tags: php, guzzle

I have a pound/hash symbol in a query string and while sending the get request with PHP Guzzle 6 it is not being encoded properly.  A sample request:

https://10.1.10.1/vmrest/users?query=(alias%20is%20UserWithAPoundSign%2318)

is sent as:

https://10.1.10.1/vmrest/users?query=(alias%20is%20UserWithAPoundSign#18)

I see there was some work in relation to this issue:

[How to disable URL encoding in Guzzle 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30865150/how-to-disable-url-encoding-in-guzzle-6)

but it doesn't look like the pound/hash is accounted for.  Is this a bug or something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what version of guzzle are you using? it looks like [it was fixed](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1121#issuecomment-111765449) in psr7

Comment: It's Guzzle 6.2.0. I checked out the commit and I don't see anything specifically for the pound symbol in that update.

Comment: Why should you have a `#` in request URI?

Comment: I'm querying an API based on user 'alias', which contain `#`.

Realizing I was a bit short sighted since the uri fragment uses `#`, would it be possible to have a client option to toggle whether the `#` is treated as a fragment or literal `#` as part of a query string?  I have to imagine with REST API's this would come up once in a while.  In my application I'll never be using this as a fragment so the Guzzle client could encode it for me instead of treating as a fragment.